# Porting python PKCS1_v1_5 encryption code to java generating different signatures

Tags: java, python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to port my working python code for generating signature to java but they both are producing different signatures. Here is my code for python which is generating the signature.

```
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(priv_key)
    digest = SHA256.new()
    digest.update(message)
    val = signer.sign(digest)
    return val
```

I am calling this function using this statement

```
signature = b64encode(sign(msg1, private))
```

Here the msg1 is

```
msg1 = 'test'.encode("utf8")
```

and private is the private key which I am importing using

```
RSA.importKey("<Location of key>"
```

I am trying to write a similar java code for implementing the same functionality with this given code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String payload = "test";
        String dig = makeDigest( payload, "SHA-256");
        Key k = getPrivateKey("private_key.der");
        String signature = encrypt(dig, "RSA", k);
        System.out.print(signature);
    }

    public static String makeDigest(String payload, String digestAlgo) {
        String strDigest = "";
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(digestAlgo);
            byte[] p_b = payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
            md.update(p_b);
            byte[] digest = md.digest();

            char[] encoded = Hex.encodeHex(digest);
            strDigest = new String(encoded);
            System.out.println(strDigest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strDigest;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String sha, String encryptAlgo, Key k) {
        String strEncrypted = "";
        try {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptAlgo,"BC");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(sha.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            //System.out.println(new String(encrypted));
            byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encrypted);
            strEncrypted = new String(encoded);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strEncrypted;
    }
    public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String filename)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA","BC");
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
    }
```

Both thee codes are generating different signatures. I feel something I am doing wrong in selecting the algorithm on Java side. I have tried with

```
RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding
```

and

```
RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
```

but still, it is different signature as compared to python code.

Any lead on this will be very helpful.

Comment: What python crypto library are you using?

Comment: Just like in python, use the [Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) class in Java for signing. Java's Signature class has the digest function "built-in", so you don't have to compute the digest separately. To get a compatible algorithm, use `Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks for your suggestion it worked like charm

Comment: @AnkitTalwar any solution??